# Asp.net Core - Read Application Insights Page Views

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

A simple enough question I would have thought, but haven't been able to find an answer.

I have Application Insights enabled on my Asp.net core 3.1 mvc application. I have been able to look at the data in azure portal, and see that the application has page views.

What I want to do now is have some way of retrieving page views back in my mvc web application for reporting.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do now is have some way of retrieving page views back in my mvc web application for reporting.

The [metrics REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/metrics/get) enables us to get metric values based on a specified [metricId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/metrics/get#metricid).

```
GET https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/metrics/{metricId}
```

To get metric about page views, you can refer to the following code snippet to [make request from your ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) MVC app.

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appid}/metrics/pageViews/count?timespan=2021-02-19%2F2021-02-24").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var val = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PvData>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    var sum = val.value.PageViewsCount.sum;
}
```

Model classes

```
public class PageViewsCount
{
    public int sum { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("pageViews/count")]
    public PageViewsCount PageViewsCount { get; set; }
}

public class PvData
{
    public Value value { get; set; }
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]